# My Enemy Dissapears when i Press Play & the Box Collider gets small

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

MY Enemy Disappears when I press play in Unity as seen in the Photos Below

Inspector not Playing

[image]

Scene View before clicking play.

[image]

The Scene View after Clicking play.

[image: Scene View while Playing]

The Box Collider Also becomes a line

[image]

Also Here is my Inspector when i'm playing i cant figure out how to fix the Warning

[image]

my Enemies Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



  public class EnemyMove : MonoBehaviour
    {

        public Transform Player;
        int MoveSpeed = 4;
        int MaxDist = 10;
        int MinDist = 5;




    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.LookAt(Player);

        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position) >= MinDist)
        {

            transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;



            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position) <= MaxDist)
            {
                //Here Call any function U want Like Shoot at here or something
            }

        }
    }
}
```

i can't seem to find the Issue maybe someone here could help?

Comment: I dont see anything as a sprite in the top one, if there is something its dark and hard to see

Comment: no, the sprite just disappears.

Comment: But there is no visible sprite in the first place ..

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add an image, i added what the Scene view looks like before clicking play

Comment: sure the game isnt in 3d mode?

Comment: What happens if you remove `transform.LookAt(Player);`?

Comment: Iggy, it Doesn't Disappear anymore but it just doesn't follow either anymore

Comment: BugFinder yes, i started the Project in 2D and eitherway everything else works fine

Comment: You're rotating it so its side on, and therefore has no width cos its 2d

Comment: From the comments it looks like it was rotating to face it so you saw a side view and its not following because its within the range set.

Comment: I switched the Scene view to 3d and that seemed to be the issue.  but i have Rigidbody rotation on Z axis locked, is there any way i can fix this issue?

Comment: just move it towards the player, dont turn it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 2D rotation:

```
Vector2 dir = (Player.position - this.transform.position).normalized;
this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg, Vector3.forward);
```

Comment: do i need to put this in place of `transform.LookAt(Player);`?

Comment: @HarounAhmad Yep.

Comment: i seem to be getting one last issue i am getting this Error in Unity `Assets\Scripts\EnemyMove.cs(25,24): error CS0019: Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Transform' and 'Vector3'
`